# Express Js - Change the way parameter is passed to an ODATA style

Tags: node.js, express, odata

I was wondering if anyone has tried / or know, of a way to make express accept ODATA style parameters.  For instance:

Standard Express style incoming parameter example:

> http://www.blah.com/user/1234

```
app.get('/:user_id', function (req, res){ 
    console.log('Test user_id param: ' + req.params.user_id);
});
```

ODATA style incoming parameter example (this is what I want to do):

> http://www.blah.com/user(1234)

```
app.use('\(:user_id\)', function (req, res){ 
        console.log('Test param: ' + req.params.user_id);
    });
```

Has anyone done something like this?  Suggestions on how to implement something close to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Express allows you to use your own subset of a regular expression in route definitions, so that would be one way to go.  See http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.

Comment: You'll need to escape ```()``` since they are part of regex.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I edited the above code.  It still doesn't work because the route resolver seems to be requiring the "/" to identify the following as a parameter.  The above edited code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jfriend00 suggests, you can provide your own regex to Express' route resolver. Something like this should work for your use case:

```
app.get(/^\/user\((.*)\)$/, function (req, res) {
    // Your user id is now in req.params[0]
}
```

See [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD).

According to docs, it should also work with "simpler" style regex inspired routing with just a wild card, like so:

```
app.get("/user(*)", function (req, res) {
    // still in req.params[0]
}
```

Comment: So I have some code that works like that now... thank you.
Follow up question though:  Using a regex resolver this way eliminates the ability to assign parameter name to the incoming field... is that correct?  IE  '/:user_id'  Instead you would always have to use the req.params[0] method.  Is that correct?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. No problem. Please accept the answer if it was to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it with *express@^4.0.0*

```
app.get("/User\\(:user_id\\)", function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    id: req.param("user_id")
  })
})
```

This request :

```
GET /User(1) HTTP/1.1
```

Will return :

```
{ "id": "1" }
```